# Is there a rule for Regular and Compact in Size Classe?

Tags: ios, landscape, size-classes, portrait

I am study `Size Classes` recently, and there is a form seems need me to memory:

[image]

As you see, I can not find the law(rule) of the `Regular` or `Compact` in the Vertical and Horizontal direction in defferent device.

Such as I have many doubt, such as :

1. why iPhone Landscape in Horizontal Size Class is Compact but iPhone 6p's Landscape is Regular?
2. Why iPhone Portrait's Horizontal Size Class is Compact?

I can not understand if there is a rule, so I can remember this form or understand this form here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iPad is regular / regular (except in splitscreen mode).

Compact width distinguishes iPhone from iPad. Compact height distinguishes iPhone in landscape from iPhone in portrait.

The Plus devices are big enough with high enough resolution that in landscape they can contain the same interface as an iPad. For example, they have room for a UISplitViewController to display master and detail simultaneously. Thus they are exceptional.